# redoing install program (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I forked setroot and renamed it mhsetroot. when I added all of the new features to it when I was running a 32 bit linux (Chrunchbang) system. now I got a new 64 Bit Laptop with Crunchbang on it. it is suppose to run 32 bit as well. but it will not install my program using ./configure - make - sudo make install.

the first time it said my .o file was not compatible or something like that. so I recompiled it then tried it again (the next day) using this line

```
gcc `-m32 imlib2-config --cflags` `imlib2-config --libs` -o mhsetroot32 mhsetroot-v1.6.2.c
```

then changed the name of the .o file to cooraspond to the previous one then did the ./configure. that worked but, now after I run the first "make" I now get this error.

```
  dude@crunchbang64:~/downloads/mhsetroot-v1.6.2$ make
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dude/downloads/mhsetroot-v1.6.2/src'
gcc -g -O2  -Wall -g -O2   -o mhsetroot mhsetroot-v1.6.2.o  -L/usr/lib      -lImlib2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lfreetype -lz -lX11 -lXext -ldl -lm
mhsetroot-v1.6.2.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:   (.fini+0x0): first defined here
mhsetroot-v1.6.2.o: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: (.data+0x0): first defined here
mhsetroot-v1.6.2.o: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
mhsetroot-v1.6.2.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
mhsetroot-v1.6.2.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux- gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
mhsetroot-v1.6.2.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
mhsetroot-v1.6.2.o:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in mhsetroot-v1.6.2.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [mhsetroot] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dude/downloads/mhsetroot-v1.6.2/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
dude@crunchbang64:~/downloads/mhsetroot-v1.6.2$
```

because all I did when I was running the 32 bit linux was find an old install makefile - the whole thing then just modified it to work with my program so now what do I got a do to get it to work again on my 64 bit Linux?

Comment: If you want a 32bit executable you have to add `-m32` to _both_ the compile _and_ the link line.  You don't have it on the link line above.  As Etan points out, your example is quite broken so it's clearly not actually what you are using: please use cut and paste directly from your terminal to the question, rather than trying to retype by hand.  Typos you make in transcription will fundamentally undermine our ability to help.

Comment: all of that is copy paste in the code area

Comment: I'm talking about your compile line, in the first code example, as Etan points out below.  Your second code example shows the LINK line, but not the compile line.  The link is failing, but as Etan points out it's likely failing because of an error in the compile step.   The compile step you quote here is clearly invalid, so we're not sure exactly how the object file used in the link line was created, so we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
`-m32 imlib2-config --cflags`
```

isn't correct and wouldn't have worked so that can't be the command you actually used there.

That `gcc` line also doesn't create an object file, it creates a binary.

You left of the `-c` argument to stop at compiling.

That's likely the problem since you then go on to try to link a binary into another binary.

Comment: I am not profishent in C++ and its been like a year ago when I first added to the setroot program so I really don't remember everything I put in the commandline to compile it, but what I put in the code area for compiling it gave me a file without the .o ext to it.

Comment: This command `gcc -m32 \`imlib2-config --cflags\` \`imlib2-config --libs\` -o mhsetroot32 mhsetroot-v1.6.2.c` will have created an `mhsetroot32` binary from the `mhsetroot-v1.6.2.c` file (note that I moved that first backtick). If that's all you need then just try running that. If you need an `mhsetroot.o` file (to link into some other binary) then you need to add `-c` to that command line to prevent linking and then you can link that `mhsetroot.o` file into a binary later. Also if you are trying to build a 64bit binary you don't want `-m32` at all.

Comment: I'm not really sure if it can be made into  a 64 bit binary, only because the code was written in 32 bit. I do not think it nessary to make it a 64 bit. all it does it sets the image to the desktop in what ever options I added to it, then changes the colors on the desk top too, program. I think staying with 32 bit is ok for this program.